# Look up value in large table based on 2 inputs

Tags: excel

I am aware of using the index and match functions, as well as the vllookup function to find a value in a table. My question involves how to best write the formula without a ton of if statements. On one sheets I have the table, and on the other sheet, the user enters in building type and square footage. If it is less than or equal to the value in the table, then it chooses that value, otherwise the next. For example a 6500 SF Type IV would look up cell E3 and would return a vlue of 1500 for fire flow.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
2   TYPE 1A TYPE IB TYPE IIA    TYPE IIIA   TYPE IV TYPE VA TYPE IIB    TYPE IIB    TYPE V-B    FIRE FLOW (gpm) Flow duration (hrs)
3   22700   22700   12700   12700   8200    8200    5900    5900    3600    1500    2
4   30200   30200   17000   17000   10900   10900   7900    7900    4800    1750    2
```

Comment: Would help to format your sample data a little better.  Also, include the formula you have already, so we're not wasting time coming up with the same thing.  Also - are the square footage numbers sorted ascending in every column ?

Comment: So it looks down the rows until it finds the first value larger than 6500 in the Type IV column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, with one caveat.  It will return `0` if the value is > than the largest number in that column.

```
=INDEX(J:J,IFERROR(MATCH(O3,INDEX(A:I,0,MATCH(O2,$A$2:$I$2,0))),2)+1)
```

[image]

---

This formula will return the last value in Column J if the value is > than the last square footage in the desired column.

```
=IF(O3>INDEX(A:I,MATCH(1E+99,A:A),MATCH(O2,$A$2:$I$2,0)),INDEX(J:J,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),INDEX(J:J,IFERROR(MATCH(O3,INDEX(A:I,0,MATCH(O2,$A$2:$I$2,0))),2)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. I am having an issue when I am trying to reference a table on the other sheet with this formula though. My formula is    =INDEX('2012 IFC Table'!J:J,IFERROR(MATCH(C9,INDEX('2012 IFC Table'!I:JA,0,MATCH(D9,'2012 IFC Table'!$A$2:$I$2,0))),2)-1)

Comment: @broncos15 look at this part `2012 IFC Table'!I:JA`  I think it should be `2012 IFC Table'!A:I`  In is after the Second INDEX.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something working:

```
=INDEX(J3:J99,MATCH(TRUE,M3<OFFSET(A3,0,MATCH(N3,A2:K2,0)-1,99),0))
```

where N3 has your "TYPE IV" and M3 has your 6500. Note that this is an array formula, so it must be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Change the 99's if you need more columns.

This will return #N/A if no value works.